Maximization of difference between log-concave and convex functions
Consider the problem
$$ \max_{x \in [0,1]} a f(x) - c(x) $$
where $f$ is increasing and log-concave, $a$ is a positive constant, and $c$ is increasing and convex with $c(0)=c'(0)=0, c(1)=c'(1)=\infty$.
My question is: what additional assumptions may be needed on $f$ for the solution to the maximization above to (a) exist, (b) be unique, and (c) increasing in $a$?
